# How do I install Mac OS High Sierra from Recovery mode on macOS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility, software-update, recovery

My computer currently runs macOS X El Capitan. I downloaded a copy of a macOS High Sierra installer, to install High Sierra through recovery mode, but it's not going into recovery.

How do I install it?

Comment: Where did you download it from? Usually the installation can be started by just running the Installer, why do you need to go via Recovery mode?

Comment: What exact model of Mac is this?, e.g. type, year. What exactly happens when you try to boot to Recovery Mode? What keypress are you using at boot? Does the computer boot up normally to El Cap? If so, why not just download the installer?